# Running a prod server using express and a webpack config on heroku

Tags: express, vue.js, heroku, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Webpack newbie and first time using Express to spin up a web server.

I have a Vue app running locally using `webpack-dev-server` and I'm looking to have the app running on Heroku as well. I know I cannot use `webpack-dev-server` for prod so I looked for advice. The recommendation given to me is to use an Express server and this is where my struggles begin.

My app comes with a boilerplate `webpack.config.js` file that looks like so:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

const path = require('path');

function resolvePath(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir);
}

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const target = process.env.TARGET || 'web';
const isCordova = target === 'cordova';

module.exports = {
  mode: env,
  entry: {
    app: './src/js/app.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: resolvePath(isCordova ? 'cordova/www' : 'www'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js',
    publicPath: '',
    hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
    hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolvePath('src'),
    },
  },
  devtool: env === 'production' ? 'source-map' : 'eval',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    compress: true,
    contentBase: '/www/',
    disableHostCheck: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: 1000,
    },
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
      }),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(mjs|js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          resolvePath('src'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/framework7'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/framework7-vue'),

          resolvePath('node_modules/template7'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/dom7'),
          resolvePath('node_modules/ssr-window'),
        ],
      },

      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          env === 'development'
            ? 'style-loader'
            : {
                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                options: {
                  publicPath: '../',
                },
              },
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl(us)?$/,
        use: [
          env === 'development'
            ? 'style-loader'
            : {
                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                options: {
                  publicPath: '../',
                },
              },
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'stylus-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          env === 'development'
            ? 'style-loader'
            : {
                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                options: {
                  publicPath: '../',
                },
              },
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'less-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc)ss$/,
        use: [
          env === 'development'
            ? 'style-loader'
            : {
                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                options: {
                  publicPath: '../',
                },
              },
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac|m4a)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'media/[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env),
      'process.env.TARGET': JSON.stringify(target),
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    ...(env === 'production'
      ? [
          new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
            cssProcessorOptions: {
              safe: true,
              map: { inline: false },
            },
          }),
          new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        ]
      : [
          // Development only plugins
          new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
          new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        ]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: './index.html',
      template: './src/index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify:
        env === 'production'
          ? {
              collapseWhitespace: true,
              removeComments: true,
              removeRedundantAttributes: true,
              removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
              removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
              useShortDoctype: true,
            }
          : false,
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/[name].css',
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: resolvePath('src/static'),
        to: resolvePath(isCordova ? 'cordova/www/static' : 'www/static'),
      },
    ]),
  ],
};
```

and my `server.js` file currently looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var compiler = webpack(require('./build/webpack.config.js'));

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: '/'
}));

app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {
  var filename = path.join(compiler.outputPath,'index.html');
  compiler.outputFileSystem.readFile(filename, function(err, result){
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.set('content-type','text/html');
    res.send(result);
    res.end();
  });
});

app.listen(port);
```

When I run `node ./server.js` locally, the server spins up no problem and I'm able to go on my way. I have a sneaking suspicion that this could be the result of the configs defaulting to `development`.

However, when I deploy my branch to Heroku, `node ./server.js` runs and the server crashes with a `FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` after hanging for a bit.

I'm stumped after spending a silly amount of time debugging. All I want is for my web app to run on Heroku. As an aside, I am using Cordova to build and run this code on mobile platforms as well which I don't want to lose. I would love a second pair of eyes to advise me on how I should modify these files.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should use Vue CLI, it comes with preconfigured `devServer`, loaders, etc.   Then  connect your app's repo to Heroku via Github and let it build/deploy.  No express needed if you don't need a backend.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code in `server.js` was not referring to my prod build. When I changed the code to point to the correct directory and redeployed to heroku, my app showed up

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

// the __dirname is the current directory from where the script is running
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/www"));

// send the user to index html page inspite of the url
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
```